# How to get the previous screen brightness value when the setting is in the auto-mode?

Tags: android, screen, android-preferences, android-windowmanager

I want to get the previous screen brightness when the *Brightness* in the *Display* settings is in the auto-mode.

I try to use the following code:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
previousScreenBrightness = lp.screenBrightness;
```

but the value of the `previousScreenBrightness` is `-1.0` all the time even though I put the phone in the dark or light place.

I can get the right value, when the *Brightness* setting isn't in the auto-mode.

I'm using Android 4.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use

```
int previousScreenBrightness = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
```

to get **system brightness value** (same with the brightness value in **Settings>Display>Brightness**).(Range from 0 to 255)

What you get (*-1.0*) from WindowManager.LayoutParams indicates
[BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_NONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_NONE), which means your current **Activity brightness value** is not override by WindowManager.LayoutParams attributes. When the value set to *0 to 1*, then your current Activity brightness value would influenced by the setting.